# How to use something like s.end() in for loop with auto?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a below program, I want to see how to condition on last element in the container when using auto in C++11, that's why this question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

void show(set<string>& s) {
    cout << "<";
    for (const auto &e: s)
        if (e != s.end())     // This is WRONG -- results in compilation error !!
            cout << e << ",";
        else
            cout << e;
    cout << ">" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    set <string> s = { "a", "e", "i", "o" };
    show(s);
    return 0;
}
```

above program outputs `<a,e,i,o,>`

I tried to use `s.end()` in the `for` loop in the `show()`, but compilation fails.

desired output :

```
<a,e,i,o>
```

Comment: I am currently developing a library that allows to simply write something like `std::copy(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), nstd::join_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", "));`

Comment: @bipll See [`std::experimental::ostream_joiner`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ostream_joiner)

Comment: @Justin Sure, except for with my lib you can also write, for instance, `std::vector<int> sink; nstd::join_iterator<std::vector<int>> i(sink, 42);` and it will concatenate vectors inserting 42 inbetween. This particular class is somewhat pythonic in number of options it provides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
if (&e != &*s.rbegin())
```

---

Or even better, print comma *before* an element. I assume it could be slightly faster.

```
if (&e != &*s.begin())
    cout << "," << e;
else
    cout << e;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but any other cleaner way to do this ?

Comment: @OnkarNMahajan IMO it's clean enough, especially the second option. Here is an another option: `bool first = 1; for (...) {if (first) {first = 0;} else {std::cout << ',';} std::cout << e;}`.

Comment: You don't need to use & when comparing, also you should use const iterator crbegin().

Comment: @MateuszWojtczak Comparing addresses is faster. Also, if it was a different container (that allows duplicate elements), omitting `&` would lead to incorrect results. *"you should use const iterator crbegin"* I'd say it's a matter of preference. In this case it doesn't make a big difference.

Comment: @OnkarNMahajan If you're satisfied with the answer, consider pressing the green tick on the left to indicate that you don't need any more help.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sure, pressed green tick, Thanks. Comparing addresses is faster, how ?

Answer (score 2):

The range based for loops sacrifice power for simplicity. Making use of `auto` looping over iterators is less fiddly than it used to be:

```
for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
{
   if (std::next(it) != s.end())
       cout << e << ",";
   else
       cout << e;
}
```

It'd be nice if there was a portable way to get your current position in a range based for loop but until that gets added to the standard you'll just have to make the choice between simplicity and flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the shortest way is to test a 'bool' variable before adding a comma to the output stream. The following code should fits your needs.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
using namespace std;

void show(set<string>& s);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    set <string> s = { "a", "e", "i", "o" };
    show(s);
    return 0;
}

void show(set<string>& s) {
    cout<<'<';
    bool add_comma=false;
    for (const auto& e: s){
        if (add_comma)cout<<',';
        cout<<e;
        add_comma=true;
    }
    cout<<'>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually get more readable code by printing first element outside of the main loop.

```
void show(const set<string>& s) {
    cout << "<";
    auto it = s.begin();
    if (it != s.end()) {
        cout << *it++;
    }
    for (; it != s.end(); ++it) {
        cout << "," << *it;
    }
    cout << ">" << endl;
}
```